# Reload wordpress page if button is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to refresh the WordPress page with a `input="button"`.

```
echo '<input type="button" name="refresh" id="refresh" value="Refresh"/>';
```

I've tried with...

```
onClick="' . header("Refresh:0") . '"
```

This just makes the page reload without the button being clicked and with...

```
if ( isset( $_POST['refresh'] )) {
        header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Comment: Use **onClick="window.location.reload();"** event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reload the current webpage using a button or other trigger. There are several ways to do that.

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="window.location.reload()">
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="history.go(0)">
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure HTML refresh, no Javascript...

```
<form><input type="submit"/></form>
```